# Rotate database password stored in a file using AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager, owncloud

I'm currently deploying Owncloud onto an EC2 instance in AWS. Owncloud used RDS for the database and it stored the connection credentials (user, password) in plain text in a configuration file. Owncloud will use that credential in the configuration file to authenticate to RDS.

Now I was asked to rotate the database password every once in a while using the Secret Manager. Ideally we have to update the source code of our application to retrieve the database password from  Secret Manager. The problem is I am not able to modify Owncloud's code to get the password from Secret Manager, it only reads the password from the configuration file.

So how would I do the password rotation in this case? Do I edit the Lambda rotation function to update the Owncloud configuration file on the EC2 using SSM? That seems like a hard way and I don't have a better idea for now. Any help would be appreciated :)

Thank you and have a great day.

I tried to find a way to make Owncloud to get the password from AWS Secret Manager instead of the plain text password from the configuration file. I wasn't succeed to do so.

Comment: Some thoughts: Does Owncloud have a API for changing the database password? If you change the password in the configuration file, does Owncloud need to be restarted for it to take effect? Why not just set a calendar reminder every 2 months and change it manually? (Automation tends to fail over time as staff change!)

Comment: - Owncloud does support database password update via their CLI command called occ. occ authenticates with the DB with the current password before doing any action (DB password changes included)
- Owncloud uses a webserver to run, we don't have to restart the web server for the password change to take effect tho.
- A policy was enforced to rotate the DB password everyday and rotate manually in case of secrets compromised. It would be a hassle to edit the conf file everyday and act spontaneously when a password breach happens.